# How to draw flowchart in the following style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

[image: Flowchart diagram for a sample Turing Machine]

I would like to create a flowchart/chains diagram for turing machines in the style as shown in the picture above. I am still relatively new to LaTeX, but I am assuming that I will have to use TikZ.

Does anyone have an idea how to draw something like this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can see, for example, this site http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/flowcharts/, http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/labeled-chain/ or http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/chains.

Comment: There are actually several packages for drawing diagrams, so you don't *have to* use TikZ. But TikZ is perhaps the most popular package (around here at least), and it is fairly easy to use. That said, with the exception of the up-left-down arrows on top, you can do that with `amsmath` alone, e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
>\underset{\substack{\downarrow_{\#}\\\#}}{L} \overset{|}{\to} L \overset{\#}{\to} \mid R \overset{\#}{\to} L\#
\]
\end{document}`

Comment: I think, thats worth an answear, as the OP didn't insist on TikZ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you can do most of that with the features of `amsmath` alone. In particular, I used `\overset{a}{b}` (which places `a` above `b`) and `\underset{a}{b}`, which you can probably guess what does.

In the comment I also used `\substack` which is intended for stacking subscripts, but in the code below that is replaced with an `array`.

To make the up-left-down arrow I defined a new macro `\ULDarrow` that uses the standard `picture` environment to create the arrow. It's not the best looking arrow, but I wanted to keep to the basics.

I also use `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`. `mathtools` loads and extends `amsmath` a bit. The feature from `mathtools` I use here is `\mathrlap`, which is a macro that places its argument in math mode, in a zero width box, extending to the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\ULDarrow{% up-left-down arrow
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
\begin{picture}(5,7.5)
\linethickness{0.4\unitlength}
\put(5,0){\line(0,1){7.7}}% draw a line 7.7 units up, the "extra" 0.2 (half the linewidth) is to get a better corner
\put(5,7.5){\line(-1,0){5.2}}% draw a line 5.2 units left
\put(0,7.5){\vector(0,-11){7.5}}% draw an arrow 7.5 units down
\end{picture}}


\begin{document} 
\[
 >
 \underset{%
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}% the @{} remove spacing around column
     \downarrow^{\#} \\
     \#
  \end{array}
  }{L}
  \overset{|}{\to}
  \overset{%
  \mathrlap{\overset{|}{\ULDarrow}}
  }{L}
  \overset{\#}{\to} \mid 
  \overset{%
  \mathrlap{\overset{|}{\ULDarrow}}
  }{R}
  \overset{\#}{\to}
  L\#
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted!
Surprised to see how simple it actually is without TikZ though.
But yeah, thanks again for the help!

Comment: But say, I am trying to figure out right now how I would go about defining a loop over multiple symbols. \overset{\mathrlap{\overset{\#}{\ULDarrow}}}{_more than 1 symbol_} doesn't do the trick. How could I go about it?

Comment: @Rednaxel59 Do you mean that the ULDarrow should be much wider?